# Using an object's method as an event handler, how do I remove it?

Tags: javascript

If I register an object's method as an event handler, I can't remove it. Am I missing something obvious, or can't it be done?

```js
function Test() {
    
    document.body.addEventListener( 'click', this.handler.bind( this ), false );
    
}

Test.prototype.handler = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += '.';
    document.body.removeEventListener( 'click', this.handler.bind( this ), false );
};

new Test();
```

```css
body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: The value of `this` in your event handler won't be the "Test" instance.

Comment: @Pointy Good catch! Binding `this` doesn't seem to help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Function.prototype.bind`, you create a new function. Store your own reference to the function, and then use that to subscribe and unsubscribe.

```
var obj = {
    method: function () {
        return this.prop;
    },

    prop: true
};

var getProp = obj.method.bind(obj);
myHtmlElement.addEventListener("click", getProp, false);
myHtmlElement.removeEventListener("click", getProp, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Each time you call `bind`, you will produce a different function:

```
func.bind(obj) === func.bind(obj); // false
```

Therefore, `removeEventListener` does not know which event listener to remove.

Instead, you should store the new function:

```
this.realHandler = this.handler.bind(this)
```

Then, you will be able to add or remove the `this.realHandler` event listener.