# use object method as event handler

Tags: javascript

Considering the following code:

```
var SomeObject = function (id) {
    this.id = id;    
};
SomeObject.prototype.Handler = function() { alert(this.id);};

var o = new SomeObject("bla");

$('#someDivId').on('shown.bs.modal', o.Handler);
```

I was expecting a popup saying "bla", but I get a popup saying "someDivId".

Is there a way to use an instance method as an event handler ?

I read [Class methods as event handlers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229080/class-methods-as-event-handlers-in-javascript) and [Using an object's method as an event handler, how do I remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321326/using-an-objects-method-as-an-event-handler-how-do-i-remove-it) but I can't transcript them to my case.

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that when you're specifying your event handler, the `this` context is not being propagated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The context of `this` depends on who invoke the function.In this case
it is invoked by the dom element.

If you console.log(this) inside the `Handler` it will log the dom & that dom has an `id` attribute, so you are seeing `someDivId` as the output

You need to bind `o` if you want to change the context

```js
var SomeObject = function(id) {
  this.id = id;
};
SomeObject.prototype.Handler = function() {
  alert(this.id);
};

var o = new SomeObject("bla");

$('#someDivId').on('click', o.Handler.bind(o));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someDivId">hello</div>;
```

Note:Here the bootstrap event `shown.bs.modal` is replaced by 'click` for this demo

Comment: Should also mention how `var o = new ("bla");` was changed to `var o = new SomeObject("bla");`

Comment: @Tyler i guess that is a typo

Comment: @Tyler indeed! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning "o" a type. Surely it should be:

```
var o = new SomeObject("bla");
```

Instead of

```
var o = new ("bla");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need `$('#someDivId').on('shown.bs.modal', o.Handler.bind(o));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#someDivId').on('shown.bs.modal', o.Handler);
```

The 'this' is $('#someDivId') in this case because the object calling is the element.

```
$('#someDivId').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { o.Handler() });
```

Place the call inside an anonymous function and actually call it and the 'this' will be the object 'o'.